# How to use the randomColor package

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do you use the randomColor package from yarn to assign colours to different columns in a table.

If anyone has an example? I can really find anything to read through.

cade is in react and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

```
import randomColor from "randomcolor"
```

then in your element

```
<Column style={{background:randomColor()}}>
```

Comment: Can you give randomColor a specific color?